# Can't migrate alias with Wordpress Migration

Tags: migrations, path-aliases

I am using the Wordpress Module to migrate from Wordpress to Drupal 8. I am trying to have the alias be set to the link value (`<link>https://myurl.com/wordpress-path</link>`). I added the following to the source:

```
    -
      name: link
      label: 'The link value'
      selector: 'link'
```

and the following to process:

```
  path/pathauto:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  alias:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: link
    -
      plugin: str_replace
      source: link
      search: 'https://myurl.com/'
      replace: '/'
```

I have also tried `path/alias` and `path` instead of `alias` but no luck.  I verified that the str_replace plugin does return the correct value but somehow it does not save in the node.

Here is my full migrate_plus.migration.my_wordpress_wordpress_content_post.yml:

```
uuid: 5b3b3b84-8d41-4a80-b1ca-c9046c269297
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: wp_wordpress_wordpress_content_page
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - WordPress
migration_group: wp_wordpress
label: 'Import content from WordPress XML'
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  item_selector: '/rss/channel/item[wp:post_type="page"]'
  fields:
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Content title'
      selector: title
    -
      name: post_id
      label: 'Unique content ID'
      selector: 'wp:post_id'
    -
      name: content
      label: 'Body of the content'
      selector: 'content:encoded'
    -
      name: excerpt
      label: 'Excerpt of the content'
      selector: 'excerpt:encoded'
    -
      name: pubDate
      label: 'Publish date of the content'
      selector: pubDate
    -
      name: post_date
      label: 'Post date of the content'
      selector: 'wp:post_date'
    -
      name: status
      label: 'Published status of the content'
      selector: 'wp:status'
    -
      name: creator
      label: 'Username of the content creator'
      selector: 'dc:creator'
    -
      name: post_tag
      label: 'Tags assigned to the content item'
      selector: 'category[@domain="post_tag"]/@nicename'
    -
      name: category
      label: 'Categories assigned to the content item'
      selector: 'category[@domain="category"]/@nicename'
    -
      name: link
      label: 'The link value'
      selector: 'link'
  ids:
    post_id:
      type: integer
process:
  title:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: title
  body/value:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: content
  body/summary:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: excerpt
  created:
    -
      plugin: callback
      source: post_date
      callable: strtotime
  changed:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: '@created'
  status:
    -
      plugin: static_map
      source: status
      default_value: 0
      map:
        publish: 1
  uid:
    plugin: migration
    migration: wp_wordpress_wordpress_authors
    source: creator
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: basic_html
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: page
  path/pathauto:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  alias:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: link
    -
      plugin: str_replace
      source: link
      search: 'https://myurl.com/'
      replace: '/'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - wp_wordpress_wordpress_authors
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `path/alias` worked. I must have been doing something wrong or my page was cached that it wasn't redirecting to the alias.

```
path/alias:
  -
    plugin: get
    source: link
  -
    plugin: str_replace
    source: link
    search: 'https://myurl.com/'
    replace: '/'
```